# Type-level removal of one type from an arbitrary type union

Tags: scala, scala-3, type-level-computation

If I have an arbitrary type union in Scala 3, is it possible to write a method that "removes" one type from the union?

Similar to `shapeless.ops.coproduct.Remove`, but for native Scala 3.

For example, if I have a union type representing a handful of different errors, and I want to write a function that recovers from one specific error type and leave the remaining errors as a new union type.

```scala
val result: Either[Foo | Bar | Baz | Bang, Thing]
val otherResult: Either[Foo | Bar, OtherThing]

// pretend syntax
def recoverBar[X, A](error: Bar | ...X)(f: Bar => A): Either[X, A] = 
  error match {
    case e: Bar => Right(f(e))
    case otherError => Left(otherError)
  }

// example usage
val recoveredResult: Either[Foo | Baz | Bang, Option[Thing]] = result
  .map { Option.apply }
  .left.flatMap { recoverBar(_)(_ => None) }

val recoveredOther: Either[Foo, OtherThing] = otherResult
  .left.flatMap { recoverBar(_)(_ => OtherThing.default) }
```

I.e. some kind of type-level generic way to do

```
[Foo | Bar | Baz | Bang] =>> [Foo | Baz | Bang]
[Foo | Bar] =>> [Foo]
[Bar] =>> [Nothing]
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do it with a `TypeTest`:

```
class Remove[A]:
  def apply[B](aOrB: A | B)(using tt: TypeTest[A | B, A]): Either[A, B] =
    aOrB match
      case a: A => Left(a)
      case b    => Right(b.asInstanceOf[B])

def remove[A]: Remove[A] = Remove[A]

type Foo = Boolean | Int | String
val foo: Foo = "foo"

val noInt = remove[Int](foo)

// It inferred the correct type:
val inferred: Either[Int, Boolean | String] = noInt

// And we get the expected value: Right(foo)
println(noInt)
```

It kinda sucks that the match is unable to infer that the other case must be a `B` but I think this is the best we can do for now.